# Want show that $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y)/2$ is injective

Tags: measure-theory, functions

The problem is about proving that $[0,1]^2$ is uncountable. I have proven that $[0,1]$ is uncountable, and so I would conclude that $|[0,1]^2|=|[0,1]|$ by finding a bijection $[0,1]^2\to [0,1]$. I think about letting $f:[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ to be defined as $f(x,y)=(x+y)/2$. This is surjective, but I do not know how to prove that it is injective. If $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ is assumed, I have no idea how to make $x+y=x'+y'$ to imply $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.

PS: If this can not be injective, I'll edit the post to add another approach. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: $f(0,1)=f(1,0)$.

Comment: Is $f(0.25,0.75)$ the same as or different than $f(0.5,0.5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an injective map sending $x\to (x,0)$. In particular the cardinality of the unit square is at least as large as of the unit interval.

Comment: I used that bijection $[0,1]\to [0,1]\times \{0\}$ and using the fact that $[0,1]\times \{0\}\subseteq [0,1]^2$. Thanks!